# Calling ReactJS component from a jQuery application

Tags: jquery, reactjs, model-view-controller

I got a requirement that I have to use a third party which is build on ReactJS. My application is JavaScript/jQuery application and I have no idea about ReactJS. I tried to find any guide or example to use ReactJS component in a jQuery application. This is a one page implementation.

I tried "npm react react-dom", but after adding the script to the html, it throwed all kind of errors. After tryouts, finally, I am getting this error "**react.production.min.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**". Even added requirejs it made it worse.

Anyone know what are the basic scripts need to be added to call a method from a ReactJS component? Forgive me, I don't know ReactJS yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was using CJS reference which was causing the issue. Changed the reference to UMD reference and all good.